# Blender cant handle 20k objects?

Tags: objects, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to build something big like palace or Egypt pyramid. Always blender gets freezing because the high numbers of clubs and planes. So, can't finish my work !!. 
My PC [16 ram - 64bits - processor 3930k - GTX 680 4GB]

How to speed up blender performance ? How to reach 50K cubes without freezing ?

Comment: You need to figure out what the bottle neck is. Monitor your CPU core usage, ram usage, GPU ram usage, etc. If it's true that it is a hardware bottleneck then upgrade your HW or get a program that uses your hardware better.

Comment: I just tried creating 25x25x25 (a total of 15,625) cubes as separate objects. I started with one, duplicated with Shift D along the X axis until I had 25, then duplicated those 25 along Y until I had 25 rows, which I then duplicated along Z until I had 25 levels. This took all of 5 minutes, and up until about 5,000 I experienced virtually no lag. My system is an i7 960, 24 GB DDR III, GeForce 9600GT 512 MB GDDR3. What I'm saying here, is that my system is more outdated than yours, so if I can do it, you **should** be able to as well, so I'm guessing HW failure or misconfiguration.

Comment: Blender as reported by some users is a lot better in large volume objects as compared to other (commercial) 3d tools. have you checked latest version of blender 2.78 i've heard it had memory optimizations for GPU, though you got more CPU mem so perhaps you better disable GPU rendering and make sure all goes CPU using your 16GB ram.

Comment: Thank you guys for you reply. but no one give me a solution !. I'm not talking about 5K. 20K make blender freezing. and way to solve this ?

Comment: If it goes from fully responsive to frozen at more or less the exact same number of objects every time, my guess is that it reaches available RAM and starts getting swapped. Is it completely frozen or does it "wake up" after some time, anything from a few seconds to several hours?

Comment: It when it reach 20K. it fully stop working. So, I understand from you that my issue is 16ram is not enough.

Comment: That's my guess, yes. Short-short explanation: The system uses hard drive space as additional "RAM", and hard drives are considerably slower than real RAM, so the system becomes slower as more and more of the working memory needs to be put on hard drive space and swapped to and fro between real RAM and hard drive. If the freeze is accompanied by a sudden increase in hard drive activity, it's a strong indication that my guess is right.

Comment: Not sure if this could helps, but I made a test with a 32Gb machine. Duplicate 4096 cubes (to 8192)  took 2 seconds, duplicate again to 16384 took 9 seconds, dup again to 32768 tooks about 2 minutes, but the last "dup" to 65536 cubes takes 16 minutes! The memory allocation does not change so much (about 5Gb), but the time changes exponentially  and the UI looks totally unresponsive during the dup. After create 65k cubes, the 3d view works normally (rotation, translation, etc.) if I select all objects, but it "freezes" if I try to select only one or two cubes of the set.